# Is it possible to configure part of an Eclipse Java project to use a different JDK than the rest of the project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java project in eclipse 4.5.2 that is compiled using the Java 1.7 JDK. I want to change part of this project (one package nested roughly 6 levels deep) to compile using the Java JDK 1.8. Is this possible?

I wish to do this because the branch of the product this project represents has already been released, but we want to update part of our testing code so we can use a more recent version of Selenium.

Comment: You can not use different Java Versions in one Project. the only way is to make different project

Comment: @Jens If you can add that as an answer, then I can accept that.

Comment: If you have a new project, you can use different Java compiler settings. If you link the source folders instead of copying them, both projects are always in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use different Java Versions in one Project. the only way is to make different Project.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that through eclipse. Because Eclipse has option to select JDK by default or you can use it project wise only.
Since Java has full backward compatability, therefore you can use newer version on whole project without any problem.